# KEDA on AKS - production ready or preview?

Tags: azure-aks, keda

This question may be outdated soon enough, but at present, the path forward with AKS and KEDA isn't clear.

Background:
KEDA offers better and more polished scaling options over Kubernetes HPA (while using it internally).
KEDA can be installed in AKS and potentially used using:
`kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kedacore/keda/releases/download/v2.10.0/keda-2.10.0.yaml`.

Two things related to its use in AKS today is unclear.

1. KEDA documents itself as [production ready](https://keda.sh/docs/2.10/faq/)

> Yes! KEDA v2.0 is suited for production workloads, but we still support v1.5 if you are running that as well..

The KEDA K8 configuration though states version as `v1alpha1` - which suggests not-production-ready (this is irrespective of AKS or not)
[Example](https://keda.sh/docs/2.10/scalers/cpu/#example):

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: cpu-scaledobject
  namespace: default
```

2. While KEDA can be installed as mentioned at the start, AKS documents installing KEDA using their [KEDA add-on](https://aka.ms/aks/keda), which they call out as preview explicitly, for [about an year now](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-keda-addon-for-aks/), so it may not change very quickly.

Does that mean that installing KEDA separately on AKS is ok and production ready (though the scaled object has alpha version), but just should not be used for Prod with the AKS Keda add-on?
Or should KEDA be avoided in AKS prod scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install KEDA open-source/upstream today which is supported in production [but offers open-source support](https://keda.sh/support/).

The AKS add-on is in preview but will offer additional support through Azure Support once it is GA. You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1479) to track progress.